# Using the groovy-android-gradle-plugin exceeds 65536 method limit

Tags: android, groovy

I have been experimenting with [groovy-android-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/melix/groovy-android-gradle-plugin) to see if we can code in groovy for android. But when I use the plugin along with some basic libraries it exceeds the 65,536 methods per dex file limit. Is there any clean/best practice way to handle such issues?

Comment: Have you considered trying to load Jars at runtime?

Comment: Could you let me know how to do that and if possible some example I can learn from. I am kind of new at this.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Seems like the best after an initial google. I'm more of an NDK/C++ lad.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

Break your app into multiple dex files.  Example [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html).

Apply the "Facebook fix" as described [here](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920). *Note; not recommended*

ProGuard of course will help but not for debug builds, only release.

Finally, there's some great information [here](https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71). Basically the takeaway is, "strip it til you make it".

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. Ultimately, I used proguard. I don't have enough reputation Points to upvote, but I have bookmarked it for later.